# Im trying to create a Rich Text Editor from scratch in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hey guys I am trying to make own customized Rich Text Editor in flutter from scratch. I browsed through internet and found that using json as datatype is a good option. But I need help on how to create the textfield from scratch and how to start

Comment: If you need help on how to put a textfield on the screen, you should take smaller steps than this and start with some basic tutorials.

Comment: i know how to put a textfield on the screen

Comment: So what is your specific question?

Comment: for exact how can i show rendered text on textfield exactly like typora

Comment: People here might not know what typora is, I don't. The flutter way of rendering rich text is the widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

Comment: but it is not an editor like textfield